# File manager for Angular

Tags: angular

Is there like [responsivefilemanager](http://responsivefilemanager.com/), which is mainly implemented with jQuery, for Angular 2. I have searched for a native Angular 2 implementation the best thing I have got was [angular-filemanager](https://github.com/joni2back/angular-filemanager). But as I see it lacks many features especially these two important ones:

1. integration with a WYSIWYG like [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/) or [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/).
2. Showing thumbnails for images instead of a universal icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use ng2-file-manager and easy file manager for angular 2

**link:** https://github.com/jkuri/ng2-file-manager

Comment: last update was 2 years ago, so the project seems dead

Answer (score -11):

Here is an example of angular2 front end and PHP as a backend for [angular2 file manager](https://github.com/bhaskar-bhatt/angular-file-manager)

**Source** : https://github.com/bhaskar-bhatt/angular-file-manager

[image]

Comment: how can I install this module ?

Comment: For that you need to contact website owner

Comment: @BhaskarBhatt you yourself are the one who owns the website, so I think it will be better that you clarify on whether it is available for people to use it in their projects or not.